# MobileFirst - WLClientLogReceiver not writing any client logs in SystemOut.log

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-analytics

IBM MobileFirst Server Version:7.0.0.0020150312-0731

I have WLClientLogReceiver adapter with a procedure "log" to receive the client logs via WL.Logger.send() method.

In device client log, i see the message "Client Logs successfully sent to server"

During this, i do see the below message in server.

[6/17/15 12:12:40:768 CDT] 0000009c ProjectManage I com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl logTransactionDetails FWLSE0275I: Starting transaction with ID 58 for 'commit'.  [project mfgulfconsole]

I have a APAR opened for Operations Analytics not loading data over SSL in WAS full profile clustered environment. So i am trying to find the client logs that has been pushed to server in my servers SystemOut.log. No client logs is writing on this file.

I even tried with HPEL Mode of log and trace the text log, nothing writes in this file for WL.Logger.send() call.

Am i searching for the logs in wrong files. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the analytics data is not stored in the MobileFirst Server logs... they go to the Analytics server and are stored in the ElasticSearch database.